# Excel Data validation in fileds

Tags: excel, validation

I need your help in solving the below question.

**Provide a condition in the excel fields to accept only values that are in percentage with 2 decimals using data validation.**

My solution:

I have used this custom formula:

```
=MOD(C10*100,1)=0
```

but it is not working as per the requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by `percentage with 2 decimals`? Can you show an example?

Comment: ex-1 : 2.35% should be accepted but 2.356% should throw an error.

Comment: So if decimal part is 2 digit then it is okay. If decimal part is more than two digit then shouldn't accept right? How you calculating the value in cell? Are you just manually inputting the value to cell or use any formula?

Comment: Right. Manually inputting the value to cell directly. user inputted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula

```
=LEN(A1-INT(A1))<=4
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the formula. It not allowing more than two digit.

Comment: when % values are added formula is rejecting the value and it is accepting only non % values.

Comment: You are adding with % symbol? Then need some changes in formula.

Comment: @rajkiran Then use `=LEN(A1*100-INT(A1*100))<=4` Just multiply the cell value with 100.